# How do I change the result from Int to Float data type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have make electricity bill calculator application in VS 2010 using MFC application.

The program working but I cant print out the result in float.

This is my calculation code :

```
void CLAB10Dlg::OnBnClickedTotal()
{


float num1; 
    float result;
    num1 = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_NUM1);

CButton* domesticButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_DOMESTIC);
CButton* industrialButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_INDUSTRIAL);
CButton* commercialButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMMERCIAL);

if(domesticButton -> GetCheck())
{
    result = 31.66 * num1;
SetDlgItemInt(IDC_RESULT,result);
}
else if(industrialButton -> GetCheck())
{
    result = 36.15 * num1;
SetDlgItemInt(IDC_RESULT,result);
}
else if(commercialButton -> GetCheck())
{
    result = 47.92 * num1;
SetDlgItemInt(IDC_RESULT, result);
}

}
```

for example, my `num1` = 1.

result = 31.66 * num1

result = 31

Where should I change so I can print out the `result` in float.

Comment: You must use SetDlgItemText() instead.

Comment: Looks like you have to use [`SetDlgItemText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521(v=vs.85).aspx) and to do `float` to string conversions and vice versa.

Comment: `CString s; s.Format(_T("%f"), result); SetDlgItemText(IDC_RESULT, s);`

Comment: @AlexFarber where should I put this code? After my calculation? Because I try put this code after my 'SetDlgItemInt(IDC_RESULT,result);' I can`t get the answer

Answer (score 2):

[SetDlgItemInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645518(v=vs.85).aspx) sets the control text to an unsigned integer and thus converts your float value to an unsigned integer.

You should rather use [SetDlgItemText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521(v=vs.85).aspx) to visualize your float value, e.g.

```
CString text; 
text.Format(_T("%f", result); // This will preserve your float format
SetDlgItemText(IDC_RESULT, text);
```

Comment: should I change my declaration float num1 and float result? Can you show me how I change my code and with the commend (//)

Comment: @Newbie you can calculate your result and then use the code I posted

Comment: I try your code and get this ''s' : undeclared identifier'

Comment: @Newbie fixed a typo, take a look at the documentation anyway

Comment: This how i do 'result = 31.66 * num1; CString text; text.Format(_T("%f", result)); SetDlgItemText(IDC_RESULT, text);' But the result is '0.0000'

Comment: At this point are you sure num1 isn't 0? Try to get an unsigned int out of `GetDlgItemInt` and cast it to a float with `(float)`

Comment: Num1 is my input. Example, I insert num1 is 2. result = 31.66 * 2. But I still get 0.0000 in the result

Answer (score 1):

```
CString text; 
text.Format(_T("%f"), result); // This will preserve your float format
SetDlgItemText(IDC_RESULT, text);
```

You have missed the bracket.